# how to define array without its size and add items to it?

Tags: c#, arrays

I want to add the below data into array in c# , but I dont know the size of the array. 
I have searched many questions, but all array's size in predefine.

I dont want to define the the size of the array as data will come from DB run-time.

so how can I add the below data into Array in C# ?

```
 (Id : Value) 


    1 : 500 ,
    2 : 700 , 
    3 : 800 ,
    4 : 900 ,
    .
    .
    .
    Upto no of records into DB.
```

I have the below code and want to add data to array like below code.

```
   foreach (var LocationObj in Location)
        {
           StockList.Add(InventoryDTO.Id, InventoryDTO.Quantity);
        }
```

Cant use dictionary, as key might be duplicate.

Want simple code of 2D List...

Comment: Why not use a List?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you want to use an array instead of something that's easier to handle dynamically?

Comment: And eventually if you want to return an array, you can just convert the List back to an Array

Comment: If I can convert List into Array (2-D) then its fine... may get any link to add the data in 2D list ?

Comment: You should also consider using [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp)

Comment: @user1650894 but why would you need to use array specifically?

Comment: I have to pass it to Javascript... I am not sure list will work their...

Comment: @user1650894: if you need an array you can always call List.toArray()

Comment: List is the best option, however if still you need array then you can use yourList.ToArray() to get list type array. Every single item in array will be object of your list type.

Comment: Can you provide the simple example for adding 2D list ?

Comment: @user1650894 `List<List<YourClass>> my2DList = new List<List<YourClass>>();` and then fulfill it like this `my2DList.Add(new List<YourClass>())` or another way: `var internalList = new List<YourClass>()` and `my2DList.Add(internalList);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### You can use a List and convert it to an array.

```
List<Location> StockList = new List<Location>();
// add some data
 foreach (var LocationObj in Location)
 {
     StockList.Add(InventoryDTO);
 }
// convert to array
var myArray = StockList.ToArray();
```

#### If your Location is unique you should use a dictionary.

```
 Dictionary<int, Location> StockList= new Dictionary<int, Location>();
 foreach (var LocationObj in Location)
 {
     StockList.Add(InventoryDTO.Id, InventoryDTO.Quantity);
 }
```

### More Information

- [MSDN - List Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [MSDN - Dictionary Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: key might be duplicate... what other options ?

Comment: In this case, use a List.

Comment: but I dont found any sample where 2D list is used...

Comment: i dont understand your comment, sorry. What are you missing in my answer ?

Comment: I can use the 2D List... but I want the sample of it... I dont want to add the object in list, I want to add 2 integer values into list.

Comment: But your id is not unique in the list ?

Comment: no...It might be duplicate...it will nice if you provide me sample or link of , adding the data in 2D list...

Answer (score 2):

Well, if in all answers people tell you array's size has to be predefined, it means the array's size has to be predefined.

Use dynamic size collections, like [List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`List`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of `array`.

```
List<Location> Locations = new List<Location>();
// There is no need to specify a size
// Now you can add how many Location instances you need
```

Edit: If you need to store multiple values, use a `List` of [`Tuple`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
// We assume Id and Quantity are integers
List<Tuple<int, int>> StockList = new List<Tuple<int, int>();
foreach (var LocationObj in Location)
    {
       StockList.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(InventoryDTO.Id, InventoryDTO.Quantity));
    }
```

Comment: want to add 2 dimensional data...

Comment: @user1650894 As already suggested, Dictionary would be better if it's actually IDs and values, but you can also use a `List<Tuple<int, int>>` if you really want to. And even convert that to an array with `ToArray()`

Comment: Cant use dictionary, Key can be duplicate...

Answer (score 0):

Try ArrayList

```
ArrayList myAL = new ArrayList();
myAL.add("itemname");
```

Checkout here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.aspx

Comment: Why would you recommend ArrayList over List<T>?

Comment: you can also do it with List<T> but I like ArrayList its a little simpler than List<T>. your call...